# Estimating error under Taylor expansion of denominator

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion, fractions, error-propagation

I have the following function

$$f = \frac{a^2bc}{(\sqrt{b^2c^2 + abc\delta}- bc)^2}$$

and am given that $0 < \delta \ll \frac{bc}{a}$ and $a, b, c > 0$. This motivates me to consider the Taylor expansion of the term under the square root to obtain

$$\sqrt{b^2c^2 + abc\delta} = bc\left(1 + \frac{a\delta}{2bc} + O\left(\frac{a\delta}{bc}\right)^2+\  ... \right)$$

Can I ignore these higher order terms and claim the following?

$$f \approx \frac{4bc}{\delta}$$

If so, what is the error in $f$ that I make due to this approximation?

Comment: Use long division to find how the error moves from out of the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering $$f = \frac{a^2bc}{(\sqrt{b^2c^2 + abc\delta}- bc)^2}$$
where $0 < \delta \ll \frac{bc}{a}$.

Let $\delta=k \frac{bc}{a}$ to make
$$f=\frac{a^2}{b c} \frac{1}{ \left(\sqrt{k+1}-1\right)^2}$$ Now, develop as Laurent series for small $k$ to get
$$f=\frac{a^2}{b c} \left(\frac{4}{k^2}+\frac{2}{k}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{k}{8}+O\left(k^2\right) \right)$$ Back to $\delta$

$$f=\frac{4 b c}{\delta ^2}+\frac{2 a}{\delta }-\frac{a^2}{4 b c}+\frac{a^3 \delta
   }{8 b^2 c^2}+\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer - could you comment on how to take the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(\sqrt{k+1}-1)^2}$? If I call that $f(k)$, I cannot expand around $k=0$ because $f(0)$ blows up

Comment: @user1936752. Sorry ! It is a Laurent series.